# How to sum up missing values per row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
'Country': ["Austria", "Austria", "Belgium", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA"], 
'Number2020': [15, None, 18, 20, 22, None,  30],
'Number2021': [20, 25, 18, None, None, None, 32],    
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    Country   Number2020    Number2021
0   Austria   15.0          20.0
1   Austria   NaN           25.0
2   Belgium   18.0          18.0
3   USA       20.0          NaN
4   USA       22.0          NaN
5   USA       NaN           NaN
6   USA       30.0          32.0
```

and I want to sum up the nan values per each country. E.g.

```
    Country       Count_nans
    Austria       1
    
    USA           4
```

I have filtered the dataframe to leave only the rows with nans .

```
df_nan = df[df.Number2021.isna() | df.Number2020.isna()]

    Country   Number2020    Number2021
1   Austria   NaN           25.0
3   USA       20.0          NaN
4   USA       22.0          NaN
5   USA       NaN           NaN
```

So it looks like a groupby operation? I have tried this.

```
nasum2021 = df_nan['Number2021'].isna().sum()

df_nan['countNames2021'] = df_nan.groupby(['Number2021'])['Number2021'].transform('count').fillna(nasum2021)
df_nan
```

It gives me 1 nan for Austria but 3 for the United States while it should be 4.  so that is not right.
In my real dataframe, I have some 10 years and around 30 countries. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution for processing all columns without `Country` - first convert it to index, test missing values and aggregate `sum`, last sum columns:

```
s = df.set_index('Country').isna().groupby('Country').sum().sum(axis=1)
print (s)
Country
Austria    1
Belgium    0
USA        4
dtype: int64
```

If need remove `0` values add [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = s[s.ne(0)]
```

Comment: thank you. this totally solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
df.filter(like='Number').isna().sum(1).groupby(df['Country']).sum()
```

output:

```
Country
Austria    1
Belgium    0
USA        4
dtype: int64
```

or, filtering the rows with NaN first to only count the countries with at least 1 NaN:

```
df[df.filter(like='Number').isna().any(1)].groupby('Country')['Country'].count()
```

output:

```
Country
Austria    1
USA        3
Name: Country, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pandas.DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) along with [`pandas.DataFrame.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html#pandas-dataframe-isna):

```
>>> df.groupby('Country').agg(lambda x: x.isna().sum()).sum(axis=1)
Country
Austria    1
Belgium    0
USA        4
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.groupby('Country').apply(lambda x: x.isna().sum().sum())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You're not grouping by countries here.